# SonarQube authentication with LDAP not working

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm having a problem getting LDAP authentication to work.  Looking at the logs it seems to bind ok, but when i try to login it doesn't look like its hitting ldap at all and i get authentication failed.

In the logs I see:

```
2017.03.28 17:17:46 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: LDAP
2017.03.28 17:17:46 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] User mapping: LdapUserMapping{baseDn=ou=people,o=intra,dc=sears,dc=com, request=(&(objectClass=*searsorgperson)(uid={0})), realNameAttribute=cn, emailAttribute=mail}
2017.03.28 17:17:46 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapSettingsManager] Groups will not be synchronized, because property 'ldap.group.baseDn' is empty.
2017.03.28 17:17:46 DEBUG web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url=ldap://trprdirqr3.intra.searshc.com:389/ou=people,o=intra,dc=sears,dc=com, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
2017.03.28 17:17:46 INFO  web[o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory] Test LDAP connection on ldap://trprdirqr3.intra.searshc.com:389/ou=people,o=intra,dc=sears,dc=com: OK
2017.03.28 17:17:46 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO] Security realm started
```

My config has the following:

```
# General Configuration
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers=true
sonar.authenticator.class: org.sonar.plugins.ldap.LdapAuthenticator
sonar.security.savePassword=true
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=true
ldap.url=ldap://trprdirqr3.intra.searshc.com:389/ou=people,o=intra,dc=sears,dc=com


# User Configuration
ldap.user.baseDn=ou=people,o=intra,dc=sears,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=*searsorgperson)(uid={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

According to my LDAP admin, it does an anonumous check when it first comes up, but nothing is else done after that.  So for some reason it doesn't seem to be hitting the LDAP server when i login.  I don't have any local IDs setup besides admin.

Comment: Have you checked SonarQube debug logs during authentication attempt ? If needed update your question with those, + info on SonarQube and LDAP Plugin versions

Comment: I have checked and the only thing i see is the following:                             2017.03.29 14:38:08 DEBUG web[http] POST /sessions/login | time=180ms

Answer (score 1):

You have not configured an authenticated user to do the search.

That is, the first test, anonymous bind tests the connectivity. But to search for the users DN, you need more than anonymous permissions. Then once the DN is found, bind as the logging in user. But first you need to provide the LDAP DN of the user who is the proxy that can search and its password.

Also you have an asterisk (wildcard) in your objectlass search filter:

ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=*searsorgperson)(uid={login}))

Or is that formatting symbol?  I am not sure ObjectClass can usually be searched that way).

Comment: In our LDAP system anonymous has permissions to search.  According to the documentation if you don't specify #ldap.bindDn it uses anonymous to do the search right?